# what's the meaning of "stuff like that"?

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "stuff like that"?

> In Jordan, they threw us in large camp where we lived in a tent. The United 
>   Nations gave us some food and opened schools, **stuff like that**, but when the 
>   PLO started, the FBI started behind us.

Answer (score 2):

*Stuff like that* refers to the other things the United Nations did to help them, besides giving food and opening schools.